# Image display not working.How do I display an image submitted by a form, that works with all Browsers

Tags: php, html, image, data-url

I want to display an image submitted by my "preview16.php" in the "preview15.php" file. I am using base64 encoding but it is not working in IE 7. I want it in an image  tag. And I dont want to store my uploaded image in any directory.
my preview16.php

```
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <form method="post" id="target"  enctype="multipart/form-data"    action="preview15.php">
  <input type="file" name="user_image" id="user_image"  >
            <input type="submit" name="save"  />


            </form>
          </body>

          </html>
```

And my preview15.php file goes like this,

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_FILES['user_image'])){
    $file_name = $_FILES['user_image']['name'];
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'];
    echo '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.$img_str.'"   id="watermarked"/>';

   $img_src = $file_tmp;
   $imgbinary = fread(fopen($img_src, "r"), filesize($img_src));
   $img_str = base64_encode($imgbinary) ;
    echo '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.$img_str.'"   id="watermarked"/>';


      }
```

?>

Comment: retagged as your previous tagging had nothing to do with the actual question

Answer (score 0):

in the html part i would insert the image part, like:

```
<img src="preview15.php">
```

and in php part i just would output a binary file like this:

```
if(isset($_FILES['user_image'])){
$file_tmp = $_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'];
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo $file_tmp;
}
```